# TableViewCell image is not shown

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode8

I am using Xcode 8.0 and SWIFT 3 for my development environment.
I am designing the storyboard as below, but I don't know why the image in the TableViewCell is shown on runtime but not on storyboard.

Does anyone have a clue?

[image]

Comment: programatically assigning images ? or in storyboard?

Comment: Just in storyboard. (As you can see on the inspector on the right side of the image)

Comment: I would recommend you navigate into the Derived Data folder; *Command + ,>Locations>Derived Data>Click on arrow* then delete its contents. Thereafter restart Xcode. I had a similar issue with images recently and this worked for me. I actually even had to *Delete Images>Clear Cache>Restart Xcode>Add Images>Run app*

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug. Try changing the device to 6s plus or something else in `view as:` option in Storyboard. It might do the trick.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work for me...

In your Assets.xcassets, make sure you include a picture for the 1x, 2x and 3x spots. For each image.

[image: Assets]